# Problema com função mysql mysqli_insert_id()

Tags: mysql

tenho a seguinte query:

```
$ad="INSERT INTO comanda_aberta set numero='$a', data_abertura=NOW(), data_fechamento=NULL";

mysqli_query($con,$ad);      
$idcomandalast = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

quando dou um print na variavel `$idcomandalast` ela sempre retorna vazia. e no banco as informações do insert estão sendo gravadas normalmente. alguem pode me auxiliar neste problema?

Comment: Teu banco de dados usa autoincrement? Testa assim `mysqli_query($con,$ad) or die(mysqli_error($con)); $idcomandalast = mysqli_insert_id($con); var_dump($idcomandalast);`

Comment: retorno isso aki D:\servidor\www\betas bar\sig\pages\4\comanda.php:10:int 10

Comment: Então parece que retornou corretamente `int 10`, você deve estar sobrescrevendo a variavel em outro lugar do script

Comment: Entao eu percebi isso so que eu comentei a linha do var_dump e dei um echo $idcomandalast; e ele retornou vasio.

Comment: Como eu disse, sua variavel esta sendo afetada por algo, provavelmente sendo sobreescreta, tem como postar mais código?

Comment: cara o q estou achando estranho he que nao temm ais cod, so a conexção com o db , se eu dou umprint_r ou var dump ele mostra o id se eu dou um echo ou print ele nao mostra.

Comment: Você não esta mexendo com Buffer né?